# Using Git As A Base For Multiple Version Software, But Merging Downstream

Tags: php, git, version-control

I have a software that I want to offer to my clients, but they have the chance to order in changes and personal customization.

Till now I have simply done copies of the original software and done the changes there. But this approach has been a pain, when it comes to maintenance and update of the core files and functions (this is only on the development server, when deployed the "copies" that git makes will be actual copies).

I have come up with an idea, to use git branches to create those different "copies" and work there. But here is the problem, I want to propagate the changes I do in the master (the base of the software, from which all the branches start) in the branches, not the other way around, from branch to merge in master.

Is that possible with git? If not, is there any other software that can do that?

Comment: Sure. Take a look at this excellent article: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ . In your case additional branches will exist for tailored modifications based on the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master is just a branch, like any other. Nothing is stopping you from merging the other way to synchronize any branch with whatever changes has been added to the master branch. When in branch A, just do:

```
git merge master
```

And the merges in master will be added to the A branch. You'll have to resolve any conflicts like in any other merge.

Comment: 10x thas is what i was looking for

Comment: Great, just make sure you accept one of the answers if you're satisfied with them.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's totally possible. To propagate a change from `master` to another branch, you'd simply do...

```
git checkout <another branch>
git merge master
```

This takes any new changes from `master` and adds them to `<another branch>`, without changing `master` at all.

Comment: 10x thas is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you have the branch you would like to update checked out

`git checkout BRANCHNAME`

than you can do

```
git merge master
```

which ill bring all your changes from master into your current branch, the only problem may be, im not sure if it is possible to do it for more than one branch at a time.